# Array.from() with an implementation that doesn't support iterables, Google Maps JavaScript API v3 to not work correctly

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, maps

Google map was working and now asking require to change API key. After API key updation, it says

Array.from() with an implementation that doesn't support iterables,
Google Maps JavaScript API v3 to not work correctly.

How it remove this bug?

Answer (score 6):

It's possible we have the same issue.

You probably received a mail from google which annonce an API update.

> We’re writing to let you know that the Maps JavaScript API will become
> unavailable to applications using non-compliant libraries, from the
> Maps JavaScript API version 3.54, releasing to the weekly channel in
> August 2023.
> ...
> Some third party libraries emulate newer JavaScript functionality, for
> browsers that may not support them natively. The Maps JavaScript API
> will start using some newer functionality in the ECMAScript standard,
> namely Array.from().
>
> While Array.from() is available and working in all browsers supported
> by the Google Maps JavaScript API, some applications have code which
> replaces the working version of this with an invalid version from a
> library - creating an invalid JS environment.
> ...
> We have noticed that your application uses libraries incompatible with
> ECMAScript 2020, especially Array.from().

The first solution you can use is to specify the API version in the url. In that case, the earlier version from the update (april 2023), which is the 3.53.

It will look like that:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=xxxxxxxxxxxx&v=3.53
```

The default of this solution is that Google already announces its obsolescence:

> For example, you can specify v=3.53 until April 2024, after which all
> Maps JavaScript versions will require a fix to your application.

Hope it will help. I will post again if I find a sustainable solution.

Axel

Comment: This is bang on.  Thanks so much.  I'm using Qualtrics which overrides Array.from().   Hopefully I can convince them to update their code ASAP!

Comment: We have been using the 3.53 version, however, we've now upgraded to the most recent version as we were able to override the Array.from using the following code:


const iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.style.display='none';
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
window.Array.from = iframe.contentWindow.Array.from;

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I had a conflict between Prototype.js and the new version of Google Maps API with the functionality Array.from().

So I have to use a local version on my website (because i usually use https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype), only call where is use a frame Google Maps and in that local version I change the line:

```
Array.from = $A;
```

To:

```
Array.from = Array.from || $A;
```

Hope it will help,
Axel

Comment: Wow, that was my problem and a heck of a find.  So glad to have come across this!!

Comment: Thanks, I had the same issue and this helped me solve my Issue

Answer (score 1):

For me it worked simply by adding the &v=3 parameter to

> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true&libraries=places&key=MY_API_KEY&v=3

In your case it may work with another version depending on the environment you are working with.

It was Magento 1.9 for me