# Array.from() with an implementation that doesn't support iterables

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3

When support of interables in Array.From() function will be available?

GoogleMaps API will [stop](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/releases?hl=en) support of web apps that uses libs without it in April 2024.

3.54 version release notes:

> *The map is disabled when Array.from is overridden with an implementation that does not support iterables.*

What can we do to go on using jQuery?

I have updated our web app to use jQuery 3.7.1 but it didn't solve the problem.
I receive

> Uncaught TypeError: this.Wg is not iterable

when using Google API 3.54 an higher.

Comment: So what IS Wg? And why not stop using jQuery or write a replacement fn or just use Array.from instead?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] so we can see this issue ourselves.

Comment: Wg is obfuscated variable/function from jQuery...

Comment: just use jQuery 3.7.1 and Google Maps API v.3.54 - they are not compatible because of this issue

Comment: Sorry, Wg is a variable from GoogleMaps, not from jQuery, wich need to be iterable

Comment: It will take time to create a min reproducible example, so I will provide it soon...

Comment: This is a similiar problem. I'm trying now to use solution from it... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76955952/array-from-with-an-implementation-that-doesnt-support-iterables-google-maps

Comment: Seems to be related to [this](https://issuetracker.google.com/303223396).

Comment: Thank you, @rafon.... Now shrinking my big project to get it.. will check this link...

Comment: @mplungian Thank you for giving me right direction. I have found the problem myself.

Answer (score 0):

**Solved** after several day of code cutting. The problem was in two cases:

1. Redifinition of String

   if (!String.prototype.endsWith) {
   Object.defineProperty(String.prototype, 'endsWith', {
   value: function(searchString, position) {
   var subjectString = this.toString();
   if (position === undefined || position > subjectString.length) {
   position = subjectString.length;
   }
   position -= searchString.length;
   var lastIndex = subjectString.indexOf(searchString, position);
   return lastIndex !== -1 && lastIndex === position;
   }
   });
   }
   if (!String.prototype.startsWith) {
   Object.defineProperty(String.prototype, 'startsWith', {
   enumerable: false,
   configurable: false,
   writable: false,
   value: function(searchString, position) {
   position = position || 0;
   return this.indexOf(searchString, position) === position;
   }
   });
   }
2. map in window space:

   window.Map = Map;

After **removing** these two parts of code GoogleMaps start wotking witn version higher tha 3.53.